# Cannot get the real path of a file in the project folder

Tags: jsp, jstl, java-6

Within a jsp file i'm trying to navigate to load xml file. The location of the JSP file is

```
/projectFolder/layout/applicationName/index.jsp
```

the location of the xml file

```
/projectFolder/data/files/myfile.xml
```

The location of the project folder is different in each environment, example: in my local pc the location is:

```
c:\myApps\BPServer\tomcat\webapps\projectFolder
```

when i use the following code:

```
<c:set var="xmlfile" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/data/files/myfile.xml"/>
```

The value of xmlFile is set to:

```
c:\projectFolder\data\files\myfile.xml
```

However the strange thing is that if i use the xmlfile as `href` then the correct path and file is located:

```
<jsp:attribute name="rightContent"><a href="${xmlfile}">XML FILE</a></jsp:attribute>
```

Any idea how can i get the correct file path in order to the following to work:

```
boolean canLocateFile = fileExists(xmlfile);

    public static boolean fileExists(String filepath)
        {
            File f = new File(filepath);
            return f.exists();
        }
```

Comment: href attribute can refer to either URL or relative path. You cannot use absolute path.

Comment: My main concern is to get the absolute path in order to use the file in another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get root path of application from [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).

If you have relative path of file, you can get it's real path using [servletContext.getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29).

eg:

```
String realPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/data/files/myfile.xml");
```

You can also get root path of your application using [servletContext.getContextPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath%28%29). Root path can then be used to refer to your file.
eg:

```
String rootPath = servletContext.getContextPath();
String filePath = rootPath + "/data/files/myfile.xml";
```

In case servletContext is not accessible to you in your class, you can store root path of your application in init-param or properties, and can use it.